# Add more bounty to an existing bounty

Tags: discussion, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

The title says it all. I have one question and I put some bounty on it. Say 100. Now I see its not getting any attention at all. So I want to add more bounty to it. Say I want to add 200 more totaling 300.

How can I do that? is it possible?

Comment: You can offer as many bounties on a question as you want. **However, only one bounty can be active on a question at a time.** Moreover, any user may have at most [3 concurrent bounties](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/why-cant-a-user-have-simultaneous-bounties-any-more/104813#104813) at a time.

Comment: If nobody knows the answer, the size of the bounty doesn't help.

Comment: Sometimes more bounty let people look for answer if they dont know it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you can't. There can only be one bounty on a question at a time.

Instead, wait for the bounty to expire and add another one. You get the added benefit of an extra week of publicity. Of course, your initial bounty may go to waste, but [there are reasons for that, and it's not really a "waste"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136508/178438).

Note that when bountying a post for the second time, you are forced to use atleast double the quantity next time--for example you cannot bounty a post with 100 rep if you have already done so, you must use at least 200.

Comment: I believe it is double the previous bounty.  If your 1st bounty was 100 the second would have to be 200... [source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639)

Comment: @Lix: Right, thanks :)